# A SIMPLE QUESTION ON GLM in R: pvalues are 1!

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients

I'm starting to work with glm and tried to interpret this simple example, but results were not what i expected.

```
masc=sample(70:90,30, replace=TRUE)
fem=sample(40:65, 30, replace=TRUE)
pesos=c(masc,fem)
cualq=sample(1:100,60)
sexo=c(rep("m",30), rep("f",30))
sexo=factor(sexo)
ejemplo=data.frame(pesos, cualq, sexo)

modelo.ejemplo=glm(sexo~pesos+cualq,data=ejemplo,binomial)

Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

summary(modelo.ejemplo)

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-2.740e-05  -2.110e-08   0.000e+00   2.110e-08   2.708e-05  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -3.585e+02  2.632e+05  -0.001    0.999
pesos        5.432e+00  3.955e+03   0.001    0.999
cualq        3.981e-04  4.430e+02   0.000    1.000

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 8.3178e+01  on 59  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2.9368e-09  on 57  degrees of freedom
AIC: 6
```

I HOPED that pesos would be significant, with pval less than 0,05. Instead it says that none of the two predictors are significant. I do not understand why...

Comment: Search our site for [complete separation.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=complete%20separation)  You have created this condition by having no overlap among the weights for the two sexes.  Your output does not correspond to your code, by the way: the code does not include `cualq` among the explanatory variables.

Comment: Your verbatim code does not compile for me. `Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob): cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'
Traceback:

1. sample(70:90, 30)
2. sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob)`

Comment: I will correct the code. My idea was to have a predictor that is significant (peso=weight) and a predictor that does not explain the output (cualq). That is why I was hoping to receive "pesos" with a pval lower than 0.05